# Compare and Difference between datetime.now() and datetimefield from db

Tags: python, django, django-timezone

I can't find any answer to this that works for me.
I'm trying to check difference between datetime for created post with datetime.now()

example of what I would like to do in view.py

```
  if (datetime.now() - post.created_at).minutes > 10:
        Do_this
    else:
        Do_that
```

I have tried with timedelta things. Also tried strptime with datetime formats. No luck

When I print the datetime.now() i get: 2018-12-10 20:22:10.535052
And with the post.created_at: 2018-12-10 20:18:52:544396+00:00

How do I make them comparable?

Answer (score 2):

Django is giving you a timezone-aware `datetime` object. `datetime.now()` is [giving you](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now) a timezone-naive `datetime` object. You can't compare these.

Instead use [`django.utils.timezone.now()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.now), which provides the type of `datetime` object that matches your Django settings (in your case, a timezone-aware `datetime`).

Also note that `timedelta` objects, [as documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects), don't have a `minutes` attribute. They do have a `seconds` attribute.

In summary:

```
if timezone.now() - post.created_at > timedelta(minutes=10):
    Do_this
else:
    Do_that
```